# $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$,$f(0)=0$.Show that $f(x)=0$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$,$f(0)=0$.Show that $f(x)=0$ $\forall$ $x \in [0,1]$

I used the definition of derivative:

$f'(x)=\left|\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right| \le |f(x)|$

Now, checking differentiability at $x=0$,

$\left|\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)}{h}\right| \le 0$ which should give a contradiction as modulus of something is negative So, $|f(h)| \le 0 \implies f(x)=0$ But I am not confident and believe that something is wrong..please clarify

Comment: I'd start this way: $f(x) =\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$, so $|f(x)|\le\int_0^x|f'(t)|\,dt\le\int_0^x|f(t)|\,dt$. In short, the non-negative continuous function $g(x):=|f(x)|$ satisfies $g(x)\le\int_0^x g(t)\,dt$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. There are several ways to proceed from here.

Comment: My suggestion only works if $f'$ is Riemann integrable, allowing the use of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. See my answer below for another approach.

Comment: Yes, what you said is wrong. Saying the limit of $|f(h)/h|$ is $\le 0$ does not imply that $|f(h)/h|\le0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins can you please elaborate wrt your first comment? I’m interested in proceeding as such but cannot see anything obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is continuous on the closed and bounded interval $[0,1]$ there is a constant $c$ so $$|f(x)|\le c\quad(x\in[0,1]).$$

So $|f'(x)|\le c$. Since $f(0)=0$ this implies $|f(x)|\le cx$.

So $|f'(x)|\le cx$, hence $|f(x)|\le cx^2/2$.

And so on; by induction you see $$|f(x)|\le cx^n/n!.$$

This implies $|f(x)|\le 1/n!$ for all $n$, so $f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach, using the Mean Value Theorem. Fix a small $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ and define $M(\epsilon):=\sup\{|f(x)|: 0\le x\le 1-\epsilon\}$. Suppose that $M(\epsilon)>0$, and let $x_0$ be the smallest point $x\in (0,1-\epsilon]$ at which $|f(x)|$ attains the value $M(\epsilon)$. By the MVT there exists $\xi\in(0,x_0)$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x_0)-f(0)=x_0\cdot f'(\xi)$. We then have 
$$
M(\epsilon)=|f(x_0)|=x_0|f'(\xi)|\le x_0|f(\xi)|\le x_0\cdot M(\epsilon)\le(1-\epsilon)M(\epsilon).
$$
 This contradicts the assumption that $M(\epsilon)>0$. Thus $M(\epsilon)=0$ for all $\epsilon\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x_0)=M$, $f(x_1)=m$, a maximum and minimum respectively, and $c=max\{|m|,|M|\}$. Then, $|f(x_i)|= c$ for some $i \in \{0,1\}$. So, by MVT, $|f(x_i)-f(0)|= x_i|f'(d)|$ for some $d \in (0,x_i)$. So, $|f(x_i)|\leq x_i|f(d)|\leq x_i|f(x_i)|$. This implies $|f(x_i)|=0$, that is $f(x)=0 \forall x\in [0,1]$.

Is this correct? Sorry for bad english :(